# Delta tables for versioning

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am doing versioning of sde. I have done this using the ArcMap. I want to look at the delta tables in sql server.

In sql, I don't see the delta tables. I just see few tables named as a144.

How do I look at the delta tables?

Comment: You'll want to look at `select registration_ID, owner,table_name from sde.table_registry  order by table_name` or `select registration_ID, owner,table_name from sde_table_registry  order by table_name` to get the ID for your table.

Comment: Also check out multi-version views: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/882/31

Comment: @JayCummins, but how can we select  all Delta tables based on state id's (Registration_ID) ?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the add/delete tables, most likely, which are the tables that follow the format:

- a<#>   (additions)
- d<#>   (deletions)

Any updates to a feature are a deletion followed by an addition. The layer_id and table_name columns in **edited** sde_table_registry (My mistake, thanks to Jay Cummins, see his comment for a simple query) will give you an idea of how they map to your feature classes.

The deletions table just shows the rowid and the state at which it was deleted. The additions table shows everything with the state at which it was added.

There's a whole wealth of information to peruse at edndoc, this is just a very tiny slice of the pie. Here's the 9.3 arcsde developer help (not sure which one you're working on):
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.3/concepts/schemaobjects/tables/tables.htm